# Change a div class if li selected

Tags: jquery, html, prettyphoto

I have a webpage with a prettyphoto gallery.Each images thumbnail has a different colored overlay(When you hover over the image).
I have 4 categories and for each category there is a different thumbnail overlay color and that is fine.

But I also have a 5th category where all the images from the gallery are displayed and here i want another color for the thumbnail overlay for all images.

Here is the html for selecting the categories:

```
<div class="gallerySelector">
        <ul class="gallerySelectorList">
            <li class="current"><a data-filter="article.portfolio" href="#">All</a></li>
            <li><a data-filter="article.portfolio[data-category~='grafica']" href="#">Grafica</a></li>
            <li><a data-filter="article.portfolio[data-category~='gravura']" href="#">Gravura</a></li>
            <li><a data-filter="article.portfolio[data-category~='pictura']" href="#">Pictura</a></li>
            <li><a data-filter="article.portfolio[data-category~='desen']" href="#">Desen</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

And this is how I call in the images:

```
  <section class="portfolio_container">

        <article class="portfolio" data-category="grafica">
            <section class="thumbImage">
                <img src="images/gallery/afirmarea-thumb.jpg" alt="" class="fullwidth">
                <div class="grafica-wrap">
                    <div class="thumbText">
                        <h3 class="sectionTitle">Afirmarea</h3>
                        <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. </p>
                        <a class="thumbLink" href="images/gallery/afirmarea.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ac augue at erat hendrerit dictum."></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </article>
```

Is it possible with jquery to change the `<div class="grafica-wrap">`(this adds the thumbnail overlay and i have one for each menu item[category] with a different one when this is active:

```
<li class="current"><a data-filter="article.portfolio" href="#">All</a></li>
```

Comment: can you please clarify what class you want to change to what class, and of which element.

Comment: If you open the page:www.cristinagaurean.com/test under portfolio you can see i have 5 categories:all,grafica,gravura,pictura,desen.If i select "all" which in html is ' <li class="current"><a data-filter="article.portfolio" href="#">All</a></li> ' then i want to change every div class which has gravura-wrap or grafica-wrap or pictura-wrap or desen-wrap to an other class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using id `"all"`, to make sure that it doesn't happen on clicking another element with class `current`.

```
<li class="current" id="all"><a data-filter="article.portfolio" href="#">All</a></li>
```

Now if you meant clicking by *selecting*,

Detect if `all` is clicked, and change `class` of all elements with class gravura-wrap or grafica-wrap or pictura-wrap or desen-wrap, to other-class.

```
$("#all").click(function(){
    $(".gravura-wrap, .grafica-wrap, .pictura-wrap, .desen-wrap").removeClass().addClass("other-class");
});
```

Hope this helps, if it doesn't let me know if I got you wrong.

Comment: Well this didn't do anything :(

Comment: check this fiddle to see how this works. http://jsfiddle.net/ybPzP/9/ Do you understand what I am trying to do here? Have I got your question right?

Comment: well i don't understand :(.I just want somehow to change that overlay color when the <li class='current'> is selected.I can give you the whole code if you want it.

Comment: No, tell me do you mean clicked by selected. i.e. when 'All' tab is clicked

Comment: No,not clicked.I meant when it is active.When you load the page that is the one which is active.

Comment: okay, i get that is the one which is current, So you want to change class of the element which already has class 'current'?

Comment: I will explain again.When the first <li> is active/selected/clicked all my images from the gallery are displayed together,they are not filtered.For each <li> a data-category is assigned and i give a data-category for each image so the gallery to be filterable.The first <li> doesn't have a data-category assinged in order to display everything.And for each data-category i created a <div class='grafica-wrap'>,<div class='pictura-wrap'> etc. which gives them a colored overlay.And if i am on the ALL tab,which is the first i want to change all the div classes that i mentioned with an other one..

Comment: ...so all the images to have the same overlay color when you are in the ALL tab viewing all the images.

Comment: No,that is not it.I do not want to modify anything on the menu.Check this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/8rssL/  . Take a look at the HTML,i left a comment there with what i want to change.I hope i was clear enough ...hehe :-)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8rssL/1/ See the first li child has class current, i.e.it is active so I change class to all-wrap. Also when it is clicked i.e. all is selected, I again change class to all-wrap. If this is not what you are looking for, sorry u aren't clear.

Comment: OK,this is what i was looking for :-).I inserted it to the html but it is not working.Where should i call this script? Thank you1

Comment: You must have used other jQuery functions too. Keeping this with them should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

use as this

```
$('.grafica-wrap').removeClass('grafica-wrap').addClass('your-class');
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.But i have ''grafica-wrap','desen-wrap','pictura-wrap','gravura-wrap'' and i want to change to an other class only if '<li class="current"><a data-filter="article.portfolio" href="#">All</a></li>'

Comment: This is the page if it helps to understand better:http://cristinagaurean.com/test/

Answer (score 0):

Following  your comment :

*I have*

```
'grafica-wrap','desen-wrap','pictura-wrap','gravura-wrap'
```

*and I want to change to another class only if :*

```
<li class="current"><a data-filter="article.portfolio" href="#">All</a></li>
```

---

Try it this way :

```
$('.grafica-wrap, .desen-wrap, .pictura-wrap, .gravura-wrap').filter('.current').each(function() {

     if($(this).find("a").data("filter") == "article.portfolio") $(this).removeClass().addClass('your-class');
});
```

Totally untested.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this doesn't help.I explained again to Optimus Prime(see above) .Maybe i was not clear enough :-))